# How to delete sheets older than this month

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a workbook with various sheets (sheet names are dates with this format DD.MM.YYYY)

I am using the following macro to create a new sheet, delete whatever is on a given range, and give todays date on a new sheet:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Range("B5:I" & Range("B4").End(xlDown).Row).Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Name = Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY")
```

I also want to create a new macro in order to delete sheets from previous months (everything except this month). I have tried the given solutions on this thread [How to delete sheet older than a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539745/how-to-delete-sheet-older-than-a-month) but nothing is even working.

Not very experienced with vba so any help is welcome. Working on excel 2019.

Comment: Loop through the `Worksheets` collection, split the name using `Split(sheetName,".")`, create a date from the parts of the resulting array using `DateSerial()`, determine the difference between that date and today's date by subtracting the dates, if >30 then delete the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub deleteSheetsByMonth()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, a, dtWs As Date, dt1 As Date
    Dim msg As String
    
    dt1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) ' 1st of month
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "##.##.####" Then
            a = Split(ws.Name, ".")
            dtWs = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))
            If dtWs < dt1 Then
                msg = msg & vbLf & ws.Name
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If msg <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Sheets deleted:" & msg, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No Sheets deleted", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Τhis solved my problem..Thanks a lot. I ll make sure to study the code to understand it more. I ve only just started working with VBA.

Comment: If it’s the answer then please flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub deleteSheetsByMonth()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       If IsDate(sh.Name) Then
          If DateDiff("m", CDate(sh.Name), Date) > 0 Then sh.Delete
       End If
  Next sh
End Sub
```

Are there such hidden sheets?

Comment: @BigBen Yes, you are right. Month returns an integer which is not good for the problem in discussion. I will delete the answer.

Comment: I don't have any hidden sheets and for some reason the code you gave me doesnt do anything. I dont get any errors but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @BigBen I changed the checking solution...

Comment: @SilverGerry118 Please, refresh the page (this one) and try the last code version.

Comment: It still doesn't do anything? Don't know why..no results, no nothing. Is it maybe something wrong with my file?

Comment: @SilverGerry118 - add some `Debug.Print` statements to test whether 1) `IsDate(sh.name)` is true, and 2) maybe `Debug.Print CDate(sh.Name)` too.

Comment: @SilverGerry118 If not confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: @SilverGerry118 Please, add the next testing line, immediately after `For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`: `Debug.Print sh.Name, isdate(sh.Name): stop`. Press `F8` when code stops. Does it return `True` for the second case for the names you consider them as `Date`?

Comment: Doesn't  `isDate("01.01.2021")` = False ? it does for me.

Comment: @CDP1802 No, it is `True` in my case... What is the standard `Date` format, according to your localization?

Comment: I guessed that might be it I have Shortdate 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Comment: For some bizarre reason `Debug.Print IsDate("01.01.2021") = True` gives False . On the other hand for the same reason `Debug.Print IsDate("01-01-2021") = True` is True. I dont know why..

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for all the help. With your solution and comments, though they didn't work, helped me undestand some more things. dd.mm.yyyy returns `false` , although dd.mm.yy turns `true`. Switched my date format when creating new worksheet and added some more sheets with older dates (for example 31.12.21) and tried your code but deleted the current dates (06.01.22) and left the ones with the "bigger" months..I guess i have to add a new variable about the year being smaller than the current sheet.Thansk a lot

Comment: @SilverGerry118 I am afraid that your system confuses days with month. Testing on "01-01-2021" may not be elocvent. Plese try `Debug.Print Day(CDate("01-02-2021"))`. What does it return in Immediate Window? 1 or 2?

Comment: It returns 1 in immediate window

Comment: @SilverGerry118 And did you try naming the sheets in discussion in this format and the above code does not do what you need? Did you see my comment where I asked about sharing the workbook? If not possible, please try: `Debug.Print DateDiff("m", CDate("01-12-2021"), Date)`. What does it return in Immediate Window?